# `app,use` not able to accept `express-session`'s return type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

```js
this.app.use(
      session({
        // session configuration
      })
    );
```

Passing `sesson` configuration like above throws error:

```
Argument of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
      Type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, any>' is missing the following properties from type '(string | RegExp)[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2769)
```

I am suspecting that `app.use` is usually defined for setting up routers whose first parameter is a string but I have defined a function which returns `express.RequestHandler`. Somehow, this isn't happening when I pass `passport`'s configuration like this:

```js
this.app.use(passport.initialize());
this.app.use(passport.session());
```

Can anyone help me to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Please paste us the actual line of code that has the problem into your question.  Code required to understand a question should not be only available via an external link because external links have a habit of disappearing or getting changed over time, which then renders your question useless as a long term reference to others (which is one of the things stackoverflow is trying to be).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense :) I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an issue with the latest typings for `express`, see this issue on github for further details: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/43909

So downgrading to version `4.17.4` might solve the problem.